# Why is zenity executed twice?

Tags: bash, zenity

I have the following script (called `./script`), which I want to run with `$( ./script )` because the result should set some environment variable. Strangely the zenity dialog is displayed twice before the script terminates when I run it in `$( )`, while it is only displayed once if I run it as is.

```
#!/bin/bash

export select=`zenity --list --column=select "option1" "option2"`
echo "export SELECTION_VAR=$select"
```

Can anybody explain, why it is executed twice and how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `script` is trying to affect the parent environment, you need to `eval` its resulting output. This pattern is common, and you can find a similar case done by the `keychain` tool. If you invoke `keychain`, [it spits out](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) to *stdout* an `eval`-able statement like:

```
SSH_AGENT_PID=1234; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

So for your case, you’d invoke `script` with:

```
% eval $(./script)  # choose option2
% echo $SELECTION_VAR
option2
```

Also, you shouldn’t need the `export` on your `select=` line.

Comment: Running the script with `eval $( ./script )` seams to do the trick, but what is the difference between  `eval $( ./script )` and `$( ./script )`? Both variants set the environment variable correctly but only in the last case the zenity dialog is displayed twice.

Comment: `./script` will not enable parent to `eval` the `export`. `eval ./script` is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/174721/is-eval-cat-filename-the-same-as-source-filename). `$(./script)` just runs your script in a sub-subshell; I don’t see it running zenity twice, though.